# Creating a basic facebook application with Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook

I am creating a simple facebook application using Ruby on rails and I am following the liveRail tutorial available here

http://www.liverail.net/articles/2007/6/29/tutorial-on-developing-a-facebook-platform-application-with-ruby-on-rails

The problem that Im facing is that when I launch my server it throws an error saying that it cant find the 'gem_original_require' : no such file to load facebook_rails_controller_extensions.

I have added the rfacebook gem but the error is thrown when i include the require 
require "facebook_rails_controller_extensions" in the environment.rb file.

Im not completely sure whether this is the right way to go with Rails 2 but I've between making changes when i find relevant information for Rails 2

I would appreciate any suggestions on this or any links to other tutorials too.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That tutorial is SEVERELY out-of-date and you're going to have lots of issues if you keep following it. rFacebook hasn't be actively maintained in a good 2 years. You should be using [Facebooker](http://github.com/mmangino/facebooker).

There is a good facebooker tutorial here: http://apps.facebook.com/facebooker_tutorial/

Comment: This is also now gone.  If anyone finds something, please post :)

Comment: check this blog for developing facebook apps http://www.spritle.com/blogs/2012/02/08/facebook-canvas-app-using-ruby-on-rails/

Answer (score 0):

Examine your `$LOAD_PATH` variable.

It's a common issue that your load path doesn't contain library.

Use `$LOAD_PATH<<'/usr/lib/superrubylib'` to add a path to load.

Uh, and it seems to be a best practice to use `require File.dirname(__FILE__) + "/../relative/path"` to set up relative paths.

P.S. Please, specify more data about paths and locations to let us answer your question specifically.